# AS3 Function to start download after clicking a button!

Tags: actionscript-3, file, button, download

I need an actionscript 3 function for my website, that lets people download a document after they have clicked on a button.

Couldn't find this anywhere on the net.

Thanks!
Jennifer

Answer (score 5):

[FileReference::download()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/FileReference.html#download%28%29)

```
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, promptDownload);

private function promptDownload(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  req = new URLRequest("http://example.com/remotefile.doc");
  file = new FileReference();
  file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
  file.addEventListener(Event.CANCEL, cancelHandler);
  file.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioErrorHandler);
  file.download(req, "DefaultFileName.doc");
}

private function cancelHandler(event:Event):void 
{
  trace("user canceled the download");
}

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void 
{
  trace("download complete");
}

private function ioErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void 
{
  trace("ioError occurred");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a button, and give it an instance name of `iBtn_Download`, the code to make it work will be as follows. Just paste the following code into the timeline of your project. Just change the template website address to where your document sits.

```
iBtn_Download.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, downloadDocument);

function downloadDocument(_event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.yourwebsite.com/downloads/document.pdf");

    navigateToURL(urlRequest);
}
```